# Clarification about ends as weighted limits

Tags: category-theory

The end of a bifunctor $F:\mathsf C^\text{op}\times \mathsf C\longrightarrow \mathsf D$ is the weighted limit $\varprojlim\nolimits ^{\mathsf C(-,-)}\!F$. This makes perfect sense.

However, it's also known the weighted limit $\varprojlim\nolimits ^W\!F$ of $F:\mathsf C\longrightarrow \mathsf D$ is given by the end
$$\int_cFc^{Wc}$$ and I'm having some trouble with this. First of all, I take it we're looking at $F(-)^{W(-)}$ as a bifunctor on $\mathsf C^\text{op}\times \mathsf C$. However, the fact the integral is only taken over $c$, instead of pairs $(c,c^\prime)$ confuses me. Is this just notation or is there a point here?

Comment: Yes, there is a small calculation involved here. Use the so-called co-Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Your explicit question is whether this is just notation for the end of the bifunctor $F^W$, and indeed it is. The formula for the end of a bifunctor into sets might suggest why it's sensible.

Comment: This is example 4.11 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v2.pdf); you have to invoke co-Yoneda and Fubini theorem for ends. You are precisely integrating over objects $(c,c')\in {\bf C}^{op}\times{\bf C}$

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I'm having a hard time figuring out the picture since I took the weighted limit as a definition for ends. Could you help me out? :)

Comment: The reformulation of ends as weighted lims is classical yoga I think. Sure I want to help, but please, be more precise on what you need :) you can give sufficient conditions for a weighted limit to exist in terms of simpler pieces (conical limits exist when you have products and equalizers; weighted ones exist when you have products, "inserters" and "equifiers" in Kelly's jargon). Similarly, ends exist is terms of equalizers of suitable cotensors, this is in Dubuc's book "Kan exts in enriched category theory" or in J. Gray's "Closed cats, lax limits & homotopy limits". Is this what you want?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I would like a formal justification for the notation $\int _c$ instead of $\int _{(c,c^\prime)}$, but using the formal theory of weighted limits only, i.e without the calculus of ends at my disposal and without resorting to wedges. Is this possible? Sorry if you have answered this question and I misunderstood!

Comment: It is possible, but dotting all the $i$'s turns out to be wordy; if you want to avoid resorting to the Fubini theorem for ends, you have to prove a suitable analogue for weigthed limits, in the form of a "splitting rule" for the limit of $F : {\cal A}\otimes{\cal B}\to \cal C$ weigthed by $W : {\cal A}\otimes{\cal B}\to \cal V$. It's easy to find such a rule when $W = U\otimes V$: $\lim^U (\lim^V F)\cong \lim^{U\otimes V}F \cong \lim^V(\lim^U F)$.